# Redis performance issues when using redis hashmap vs pickled dict

Tags: python, performance, redis

I'm currently trying to optimize my redis calls to a local redis instance, but I am having severe performance penalties when using the redis hash map over just storing a pickled python dictionary under a single key. It seems there is nothing I can do to further optimize.

To **set** the data, I used two alternative experiments:

1 - Native Redis Hashmap:

```
r = redis.Redis(...)
fields = ['field1', 'field2', ..., 'field1000']
data = {'key1': 'val1', ..., 'key50', 'val50'}
for field in fields:
    for k, v in data.items():
        r.hmset(field, {k:v})
```

2 - Pickled dictionary:

```
r = redis.Redis(...)
fields = ['field1', 'field2', ..., 'field1000']
data = {'key1': 'val1', ..., 'key50', 'val50'}
for field in fields:
    r.set(field, pickle.dumps(data))
```

To **retrieve** the data for these two methods, I used:

1 - Native Redis Hashmap:

```
r = redis.Redis(...)
p = r.pipeline()
for field in fields:
    # I have also tried using hmget on select fields rather than hgetall, but for this example, hgetall will suffice
    p.hgetall(field)
results = p.execute()
```

2 - Pickled dictionary

```
r = redis.Redis(...)
results = r.mget(fields)
unpickled_results = [pickle.loads(x) for x in results]
```

When I fetch the data, using a single user over a period of 10 seconds, the results are blaring, which is to be expected since there are more commands for the first solution:

1 - Native Redis Hashmap using 1 concurrent user over 10 seconds:

```
Average: 125.98 ms
Median: 122.49 ms
Number of requests per second: 7.9
```

2- Pickled dictionary using 1 concurrent user over 10 seconds:

```
Average: 10.89 ms
Median: 10.35 ms
Number of requests per second: 90.2
```

The second solution **should** obviously be faster, but it is a very poor way of storing this data given that the entire dictionary must be fetched and set in order to update a single key.

I am just curious if I am doing anything wrong here with option 1, if there are any better practices within redis, and if there are any preferred alternatives aside from redis when dealing with this kind of data and querying. I have also tried threading which did improve performance but still much slower when compared to option 2.

Also, for additional context, I need to be able to handle up to a thousand requests per second, in which each request performs the retrieval methods shown above (for up to 1000 fields, and 50 key-value pairs).

Comment: You are fetching the entire dictionary per field. what's up with that?

Comment: Exactly, that is why I was saying I don't like the solution. But the numbers suggest it is optimal for performance when compared to the native redis hashmap.

Comment: Also to make it clear, if you are referring to the hgetall in option 1, I should have further clarified the comment in there, which is basically saying that I have tried selecting only those values which are needed (roughly 20 keys, using hmget), and actually the perf metrics you are seeing reflects that use case

Comment: but you can just do one hgetall and get it over with, the for loop is unnecessary.

Comment: You can't pass multiple fields to an hgetall in redis-py

Comment: you don't need to! just get them all at once.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't an option. I should have shown that there are actually millions of fields, and I only want the hash map for 1000 of them. And the 1000 that I select is dynamic, so it will always vary

Comment: So just issue one hmget command

Comment: The structure is:

    {"field1": {"key1":"value1"},
    {"field2": {"key1":"value1"},
    {...: ...},
    {"field1000": "{"key1":"value1"}}

an hmget can only be executed per field, so I would need 1000 hmgets.

Comment: That's okay if you do it with a pipeline.

Comment: Yeah that's what I wanted to do, but as you can see the performance is much worse using a pipeline vs mget with pickled dictionaries.